# How to manage test output with google test in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am developing C++ code with Eclipse CDT. For unit testing I use google test which I integrated into Eclipse via the "C++ Unit Testing" plugin. A problem now occurs when tests generate output to stdout, e.g., as in the example below.

Test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(TestSuite, TestCase) {
    std::string s = "str";
    std::cout << s;
    ASSERT_STREQ(s.c_str(), s.c_str());
}
```

AllTest.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

After building and running a suitable run configuration (for "C/C++ Unit" with "Google Tests Runner"), the "C/C++ Unit" tab displays an error message on the top: "Unkown error during parsing Google Test module output: Unexpected test module output."

When I run the test inside Eclipse as an application, it passes and the console shows the correct output. Tests also pass with the plugin as long as they do not generate any output (e.g., change the string in Test.cpp to the empty string, `std::string s = "";`)

Is there any workaround to allow the execution of tests that generate output via the plugin? I know that I could, e.g., write the output to an ostream and and set that to be an ofstream during testing. However, I would prefer to test without any changes to the source code. Any ideas?

I am not so used to programming in C++, so thanks a lot for any advice.

P.S.: I am using Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0).

Comment: Where did you get the "C++ Unit Testing" plugin from? Is it [this one](http://cute-test.com/)? If so, I would suggesting [contacting its developers](http://cute-test.com/projects/cute/wiki/Contact), as the issue seems to be related to the plugin.

Comment: Actually, that is a good question. I installed it according to [these instructions](https://www.cososo.co.uk/2015/10/using-google-test-with-cdt-in-eclipse/). I.e., directly in Eclipse via "Help" --> "Install New Software" --> "C/C++ Unit Testing Support". Unfortunately, there is hardly any further information about the tool, it seems more like some sort of official Eclipse Extension. I am pretty sure it is not the one you linked though. From what I get that plugin is specifically for integrating the CUTE framework into Eclipse and not any other testing frameworks.

Comment: You're right, it looks like this plugin is part of Eclipse CDT itself. Could you please [file a CDT bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT)?

Comment: Actually, you may be running into [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479289) which is already on file.

Comment: I had actually already found the bug report you mention. However, the report refers specifically to type parametrized tests, which is not the case here. Of course in the end it might still be the same bug producing the error. I will file a report, I tried right now but there was some issue with the creation of the Eclipse Account.

Comment: Filed a report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not a problem if a test produces console output as long as the output string ends with a newline character. E.g.,

```
std::cout << "someoutput\n";
```

works fine.

When having multiple outputs, it seems to suffice that the last output of any test case ends with the newline character:

```
std::cout << "someoutput1";
...
std::cout << "someoutput2\n";
```

Note that (at least as of now) this works even if the test fails in between the two outputs. This is because in the event of a test failure gtest produces some additional output and the extension apparently only requires to match parts of that. Of course, this might possibly stop working with any updates to either gtest or the Unit Testing extension.

Anyways, for my purposes and probably those of some others these restrictions are acceptable.